# Configuring JMS over a Weblogic Cluster

Tags: jms, weblogic, cluster-computing

I have a setup of 2 WLS managed servers configured as part of a WLS cluster.

1) The requirement is to send requests to another system and receive responses using JMS as interface.

2) The request could originate from either of the Managed Servers. So the corresponding response should reach the managed server which originated the request.

3) The external system (to which requests are sent) should not be aware of how many managed servers are in the cluster (not a must have requirement)

How should JMS be configured for meeting these requirments?

Answer (score 4):

Simple! Setup a response queue for each managed server and add a "reply-to" field in the  messages you send to the other system. The other system will then ask the request where to send the reply. Deploy one Message Driven Bean (MDB) on each managed server (i.e. not on the cluster, one per managed server) to consume reply messages send to reply queues. Note that you might want to use clustered reply queues and persistent messages for load balancing and failover.

This is actually a combination of the [Request-Reply](http://www.eaipatterns.com/RequestReply.html) and the [Return Address](http://www.eaipatterns.com/ReturnAddress.html) patterns and is illustrated by the picture below:

[image]

Comment: I am looking for a JMS based solution.

Comment: Huh? What the hell do you mean with *I'm looking for a JMS based solution*? Isn't a queue a **JMS** destination? Isn't a MDB (Message Driven Bean) the standard way to consume **JMS** messages? Dude, I **am** proposing a JMS based solution...